# Lua code explanation (related to RNNs)

Tags: lua, torch

I am trying to understand a portion of JcJohnson/Karpathy's code for RNN written in Lua and Torch.  You can find the complete project at github here if you are curious.

https://github.com/jcjohnson/torch-rnn

The portion I need help with is below which is from the LanguageModel.lua file:

```
if #start_text > 0 then
    if verbose > 0 then
      print('Seeding with: "' .. start_text .. '"')
    end
    local x = self:encode_string(start_text):view(1, -1)
    local T0 = x:size(2)
    sampled[{{}, {1, T0}}]:copy(x)
    scores = self:forward(x)[{{}, {T0, T0}}]
    first_t = T0 + 1
else
```

For example I don't know what these mean.

```
:view((1, -1)
:size(2) 
:copy(x) 
sampled[]
```

Do you know what these mean or where I can find a reference for them?

thank you

Comment: read the language specs for lua itself first?

Answer (score 0):

you may take some Torch tutorials [here](http://torch.ch/docs/tutorials.html) or check the docs for Torch at [github repo](https://github.com/torch/torch7/blob/master/doc/tensor.md)

Comment: Hi Chen, these helped a lot, thank you.  Only one line I cannot figure out now is this: scores = self:forward(x)[{{}, {T0, T0}}] , any thoughts what the [ ] brackets enclose?  I understand self:forward(x) but why the extra items after that and what do they mean?

Comment: `self:forward(x)` return a new tensor, brackets [] is indexing operator to select elements in the new tensor. you can see more indexing operator [here](https://github.com/torch/torch7/blob/master/doc/tensor.md#tensor--dim1dim2--or--dim1sdim1e-dim2sdim2e-).